# Resizeable matrix in GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matrix

I am currently programming some experimental design code, I have the code in principle worked out and running perfectly but now I've been asked to make a GUI to make it more user friendly. I'm encountering several issues but this is the main big one.

at the initial stage I input two parameters (P and L) these values are called back many times during the code but the first part is that P and L define the size of a matrix that the user is to fill in.

I want P and L to be popups with values from 2-6 and 2-4 respectively and for when the user selects these values a blank matrix (ready for editing) to be re sized on the GUI to match.

How would I do this? (I've never had much look when it comes to GUI's)

Comment: Are you able to do it without 'resizing'? And, have you tried this? http://www.mathworks.nl/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/uitabledemo.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the [`uicontrol`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) of type `popupmenu` for `P` and `L`. Not sure how you would then create a blank matrix of the correct dimensions for editing, but this [working example](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_guis/adding-components-to-the-gui.html#brqy_u1-1) is a good introduction for writing GUIs.

EDIT: [this example](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/examples/displaying-matrix-data-in-a-gui.html) shows displaying a matrix as a table, the code could be a callback to a pushbutton or other uicontrol, and could use the values of the popupmenu as the dimensions of the matrix/table.

Comment: Also check this video: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/videos/creating-a-gui-with-guide-68979.html

Comment: thanks I'm checking out that working example.
The EDIT example you sent me is what I'm running in my normal code, the normal code has a series of figures and tables pop up during the running with the data and some input boxes but as the code is quite long and they'll be lots of data entry it can get quite confusing which is why im looking to combine everything onto one single GUI